# Dependent object on view does not get invalid after re-comping view

Tags: object, view, oracle11g, dependencies, schema

According to [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/dependencies.htm#CNCPT1862) when you recompile a view (as below) modifying column list. Its dependent object `refvirew_intab` which is inserting into corresponding table should become `invalid`. But I see `refvirew_intab` happens to be still `valid`. Am I missing anything from doc.

Creating view `vextest`:

```
create or replace VIEW vextest as (select num1,num2 from test);
```

Creating Dependent object `refvirew_intab` on `vextest`, which is trying to insert into table test (without specifying column list):

```
Create or replace procedure refvirew_intab is
num_var number;
begin
select num1 into num_var from vextest;
insert into test values(31,25);
end;
/
```

Re-compiling  view `vextest`:

```
create or replace VIEW vextest as (select num1 from test);
```

I am thankful if you want to suggest a different logic/ statement under which this turns out to be `valid`. But it would be really helpful if you could point where did I differ from document that I got a different result.

Answer (score 0):

From [the doc you linked to](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/dependencies.htm#g1008856), under "`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view`", it says the "Resulting Status of Dependent Objects" is:

> `INVALID` when column lists of new and old definitions differ, and at least one of the following is true:
>
> - Dependent object references column that is modified or dropped in new view or table definition.
> - Dependent object uses `view%rowtype` or `table%rowtype`.
> - Dependent object performs `INSERT` on view or table without specifying column list.
> - New view definition introduces new columns, and dependent object references view or table in query that contains a SQL join.
> - New view definition introduces new columns, and dependent object references view or table in query that references a PL/SQL variable.
> - Dependent object references view or table in `RELIES ON` clause.
>
> Otherwise, no change.

The first bullet doesn't apply because the procedure only referenced the column that remains, not the column (`num2`) that your dropped.

From the emphasis in your question you seem to be expecting this clause to affect you:

> - Dependent object performs INSERT on view or table without specifying column list.

At first glance the "or table" seems spurious, and seems to be causing the confusion; what you do with the underlying table in the procedure is irrelevant. Other clauses include "or table" when they don't seem to make sense. But actually they do, because that section of the table applies to both "`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view`" **and** "Online Table Redefinition (`DBMS_REDEFINITION`)".

So, you're reading that as meaning that an insert on the view's base table with no column list should cause the dependent procedure to be invalidated. That is not the case. It's saying that if you did an online redefinition of the `test` table then the procedure would be invalidated.

They are completely different scenarios; the doc just groups them together because the impacts are the same. When that list refers to views it is the impact of `create or replace view`; when it refers to tables it is the impact of online table definition.

It is *not* saying that an insert on a view's base table (or any other reference to the base table(s)) has any relevance to recreating the view.

Comment: Oops actually I was modifying the column list (its just I posted it incorrectly here, let me edit), at first it has two columns `num1` and `num2` , later I used only `num1.`

Comment: @sql_dummy - OK... re-written to cover why I think you're confused. If it is that bullet point that is an issue, it might have been helpful to quote that or otherwise highlight it. Your reference to your insert seems somewhat irrelevant without that context.